# Comparing 2 objects in chai, but checking for its type rather than value

Tags: javascript, testing, chai, assert, assertion

I am trying to assert a response using chai, in such a way that I compare the two objects, instead of asserting each property line by line. I'm not good with words, so here's an example using the restful booker API as an example... here is a sample GET booking response

```
{
    "bookingid": 4693,
    "booking": {
        "firstname": "firstname",
        "lastname": "lastname",
        "totalprice": 9999,
        "depositpaid": false,
        "bookingdates": {
            "checkin": "2018-01-01",
            "checkout": "2019-01-01"
        },
        "additionalneeds": "additional needs"
    }
}
```

I want to assert in a way that is very similar to the response, for example:

```
expect(response.data).to.deep.equal({
            bookingid: ?,
            booking: {
                firstname: 'firstname',
                lastname: 'lastname',
                totalprice: 9999,
                depositpaid: false,
                bookingdates: {
                    checkin: '2018-01-01',
                    checkout: '2019-01-01'
                },
                additionalneeds: 'additional needs'
            }
        });
```

The problem is of course, I don't know what the bookingid is, **is there a way to just assert that bookingid is a number/integer** while keeping this structure intact?

There are several ways of approaching this I guess, I could exclude the bookingid from this assertion, and just add a new line of assertion just for it, or I could assert each of the properties in a separate assertion each (which is how the examples on chai docs are like). But just wondering if anyone's done this before, or why it is not recommended?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Chai JSON Pattern](https://www.chaijs.com/plugins/chai-json-pattern/) plugin. Use [numbers validation](https://github.com/damian-szulc/chai-json-pattern/blob/master/API.md#number) to

> Determines if the value is classified as a Number primitive or object.

E.g.

```js
const chai = require('chai');
const chaiJsonPattern = require('chai-json-pattern').default;

chai.use(chaiJsonPattern);
const { expect } = chai;

describe('73371400', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    const response = {
      data: {
        bookingid: 4693,
        booking: {
          firstname: 'firstname',
          lastname: 'lastname',
          totalprice: 9999,
          depositpaid: false,
          bookingdates: {
            checkin: '2018-01-01',
            checkout: '2019-01-01',
          },
          additionalneeds: 'additional needs',
        },
      },
    };
    expect(response.data).to.matchPattern(`{
      "bookingid": Number,
      "booking": {
        "firstname": "firstname",
        "lastname": "lastname",
        "totalprice": 9999,
        "depositpaid": false,
        "bookingdates": {
          "checkin": "2018-01-01",
          "checkout": "2019-01-01"
        },
        "additionalneeds": "additional needs"
      }
    }`);
  });
});
```

Comment: Great!! I am going to be trying this out, thanks a lot!!